# About DbSet and DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I saw a piece of code that mixes `DbSet` and `DbContext` together. I am not strong on Entity Framework. I thought that they are different things.

Can somebody give me a little explanation?

```
public class testContext : DbContext
{
    public testContext();

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WSettings> Settings { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Intuitively, a DbContext corresponds to your database (or a collection of tables and views in your database) whereas a DbSet corresponds to a table or view in your database.  So it makes perfect sense that you will get a combination of both!

You will be using a DbContext object  to get access to your tables and views (which will be represented by DbSet's) and you will be using your DbSet's to get access, create, update, delete and modify your table data.

If you have 10 tables in your database and your application works with 5 of them (let us call them Table1 - Table 5) it would make sense to access it using a MyAppContext object where the MyAppContext class is defined thus:

```
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppContext () : ;

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table3> Table3 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table4> Table4 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table5> Table5 { get; set; }
}
```

Note that, for instance, the identifier Table1 is used both as the name of a type and as a name of a property in the defined context type.  What you see above is quite typical.  An example of a class that corresponds to a table schema is given below:

```
public class Table1 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string AStringField {get; set;}
   //etc.
}
```

Have a look here for more information: http://entityframeworktutorial.net/

Comment: Generally, I believe it is customary to express the type parameter for `DbSet` in singular form, and the property name in plural form. For example: `public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }`

Answer (score 25):

`DbContext` generally represents a database connection and a set of tables. `DbSet` is used to represent a table.

Your code sample doesn't fit the expected pattern. First, it is incomplete. Also, there are properties that really don't belong.

This pattern is more typical:

```
class User
{
   public string IPAddress { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Settings> Settings { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Settings> Settings { get; set; }
}
```